# How do I get the sum of a field from a secondary table based on the status of a third table?

Tags: mysql

How do I get the sum of a field from a secondary table based on the status of a third table?

This is to get the total number of an item awaiting delivery from a purchase order system.

I have a product table and what to know how many products are on order based on my purchase order item table's qty_ordered minus qty_received. However this should ONLY be for purchase order items from purchase orders that have a status of 2 (to rule out non-applicable purchase orders such as those that have been cancelled).

If there are no valid entries in the po_item table then a row should still be returned but with an on_order value of zero so the number of returned rows should be equal to the number of rows in the product table.

[image: ERD]

The closest I can get is this, but if there are no matching po_item/purchase_order for a product then no row is returned for and I need a row returned every time even if it is zero

```
SELECT product.id,
(COALESCE(SUM(po_item.qty_ordered),0) - COALESCE(SUM(po_item.qty_received),0) ) as on_order
FROM product
LEFT JOIN po_item ON po_item.product_id = product.id
INNER JOIN purchase_order on purchase_order.id = po_item.po_id and purchase_order.status = 2
GROUP BY product.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job, not sure if it is the most efficient way

```
SELECT product.id,
(COALESCE(SUM(po_item.qty_ordered),0) - COALESCE(SUM(po_item.qty_received),0) ) as on_order
FROM product
LEFT JOIN po_item ON po_item.product_id = product.id AND po_item.item_id IN (
    SELECT po_item.item_id from po_item 
    INNER JOIN purchase_order on purchase_order.id = po_item.po_id and purchase_order.status = 1
    )

GROUP BY product.id
```